# How to display only the non chosen language in the language switcher menu in a multilingual drupal 7 website?

Tags: drupal, hide, multilingual, language-switching

Hi. I'm a newbie in Drupal development.

I'm building a multilingual website in French and English using Drupal 7.
I'm using Internationalization and Entity translation modules to translate contents and blocks in the page.

I'm using the theme Omega, with the sub-theme Foundation downloaded from the website friendlymachine to which I added another sub-theme file to modify the CSS.

I'm already having a language switcher block which is working properly.

My question is: what code in which file can I modify (and how?) to display in the language switcher only the non chosen (i.e the needed) language?

i.e: If I'm currently using the website in French, Only the option "English" is displayed on the language switcher menu. And vice versa.

(if I'm using the website in English, only the option "French" is displayed in the language switcher menu).

Any help would be welcomed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hide the current language link (which is not link but text) for the Language Switcher block with **css**. It has a specific class for that purpose.